# JMeter - Add random files to upload

Tags: jmeter

I've a lot of files that i would like to upload to test my service but i need to pick up random files and send it. Is possible get random files and delete the file when request is completed?

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter doesn't provide any test element to create random files and delete them, so you'll have to write the relevant code.

For example:

1. Add a [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) and [Beanshell Post Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) as children of the requests which performs file upload
2. Put the following code into Beanshell PreProcessor "Script" area

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
   File myFile = new File("myFile.txt");
   FileUtils.writeStringToFile(myFile, "JMeter rocks!");
   ```

   The code above creates "myFile.txt" file in JMeter's current working directory and writes "JMeter rocks!" line to it
3. In order to delete the file after request you can add the following code into the Beanshell PostProcessor

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
   FileUtils.deleteQuietly(new File("myFile.txt"));
   ```

For more information on using Beanshell scripting in Apache JMeter see [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide.

Comment: Nice! Can i use a variable on HTTP Request with the value of path that i set on PreProcessor? And recovery it on PosProcessor?

Comment: You can capture the filename above by setting it in a variable.  For example - vars.put( "filename", myFile.getCanonicalPath() );  and in the postProcessor you can use FileUtils.deleteQuietly(new File( vars.get("filename")));

Comment: Here is a full example of [File Upload Test Plan](https://www.redline13.com/share/testplan/11595) that generates random sized files.
The BeanShell PreProcessor code would be 
`import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils;

File myFile = File.createTempFile("upload-", "" );
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(myFile, RandomStringUtils.random( RandomUtils.nextInt( 1000, 100000 ) ), "UTF-8" );
vars.put( "filename", myFile.getCanonicalPath() );`